# How to integrate `exclude: Features.Nesting` into Chris Coyier’s lightningcss CSS processing pipeline?

Tags: css, pipeline

### The context

In my bid to wrest myself off of Sass (and [Codekit](https://codekitapp.com/) as a GUI processor of it), I have with some success been implementing, in **dev**, Chris Coyier’s [Super Basic CSS Processing Setup](https://frontendmasters.com/blog/fine-ill-use-a-super-basic-css-processing-setup/), which uses [lightningcss](https://lightningcss.dev/) to do the processing and [turbowatch](https://github.com/gajus/turbowatch) for file change detection and orchestration.

My years-long Sass habit means I have become used to nesting in my authoring files, but **I don't (yet) want any nesting in my compiled CSS**.

### The stumbling block

I note that with `lightningcss`’s [feature flags](https://lightningcss.dev/transpilation.html#feature-flags) I could invoke something like:

```
import { transform, Features } from 'lightningcss';

let { code, map } = transform({
  targets,
  exclude: Features.Nesting
});
```

…but, because I am stumbling in the dark, and I am *not* authoring a Node.js based app (I’m only using Node for the processing pipeline), **I don’t know where/how to integrate this in Chris’s ‘Super Basic’ schema**.

### The setup

```
package.json  <-- invoking lightningcss and turbowatch as dependencies
turbowatch.ts <-- working CSS compiler/minifier but retains nesting
```

My adaptation of Chris’s [`turbowatch.ts`](https://github.com/chriscoyier/simple-lightning-css-setup/blob/main/turbowatch.ts) is below.

```
import { defineConfig } from "turbowatch";

export default defineConfig({
  project: __dirname,
  triggers: [
    {
      expression: ["match", "*.css", "basename"],
      name: "build",
      onChange: async ({ spawn }) => {
        await spawn`lightningcss --minify --bundle --targets 'last 2 years' ./src/css/_index.css -o ./web/css/styles-min.css`;
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

Any clues as to how to integrate `exclude: Features.Nesting` much appreciated.

---

### Update

Setting the browser targets to `> 0.2% and not dead` has the *effect* of removing nesting in the compiled CSS but that's not the *means* to the end that I'm hoping for.